# Appengine multiple modules local dev - Java

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

I have 3 java modules using Google Appengine Standard:

The first one module uses Java 7 with Servlet 2.5 + web.xml + Spring 4

The second module uses Java 8 with Servlet 3.1 without web.xml + Spring 5 using WebApplicationInitializer.

The third module is just to frontend files (HTML,CSS).

I have a dispatch.yaml that contains route for each module.

---

If I run only java8 module using:

```
mvn appengine:run OR /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/java_dev_appserver.sh,
```

It is ok, the modules run.

If I use: `dev_appserver.py theJava8Module`, happens the follow problem:

```
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.AppConfigNotFoundError: The "target/theJava8Module/WEB-INF" subdirectory exists but is missing web.xml
```

---

Before I had this java8 module, I used to run with this command:

```
dev_appserver.py --max_module_instances=1 frontendmodule/frontendmodule.yaml dispatch/dispatch.yaml java7Module/target/java7Module --dev_appserver_log_level=debug
```

When I use this command, it is ok, the 2 modules run and I can use the application and dispatch rules.

---

My question is, is there any way to run more than one module and using dispatch rules?
Can I user dev_appserver.py (python) to run java8 application that does not have web.xml?
Or Can I user mvn:appengine to run multiple modules and use dispatch.xml or dispatch.yaml?

Important: Could I run separete modules using mvn:appengine and dev_appserver, the problem is that the ports will be different, so the dispatch rules won't work.

Example:

```
dev_appserver.py --max_module_instances=1 frontendmodule/frontendmodule.yaml dispatch/dispatch.yaml java7Module/target/java7Module --dev_appserver_log_level=debug (port 8080)
mvn appengine:run java8module (port 9090)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [User Guide for the appengine-maven-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/blob/ec70ac79cc9c7e46b928f1dc3026fde71eb8a9f7/USER_GUIDE.md#how-do-i-run-multiple-modules-on-the-dev-app-server-v1) covers running multiple modules. See if it helps.

Comment: Hi, but, How I make a deploy of dispatch.yaml? My frontendmodule sends request to other modules, the dispatch has rules that forward for right module. Using mvn appengine:run can I deploy a dispatch too?

The frontendmodule it is a app.yaml:
#application: gae-microservices
service: default
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

Comment: appengine:run simply runs the app locally. If you want to deploy the dispatch file, use appengine:deployDispatch. See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven-reference

Comment: I would like to "deploy" locally, like this example: dev_appserver.py --max_module_instances=1 frontendmodule/frontendmodule.yaml dispatch/dispatch.yaml java7Module/target/java7Module --dev_appserver_log_level=debug. In this case, I could run all modules and dispatch rules.

Comment: FWIW, at least in python the local devserver can't run hostname-based dispatch.yaml rules. There are warning messages indicating it if it's the case. But there may be ways to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your module with Java7, you should know about the [deprecation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java7) of Java7 runtime environment by Google Cloud.

*Can I user `dev_appserver.py` (python) to run java8 application that does not have web.xml?*

The Local Development Server for Java is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server):

> The [App Engine SDK for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download) includes a local development server for
>   testing your application on your computer. The local development
>   server simulates the App Engine Java runtime environment and all of
>   its services, including Datastore.

The syntax description for the `appengine-web.xml` [reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#syntax) says that:

> ..... An App Engine Java app must have a file named appengine-web.xml
>   in its WAR, in the directory `WEB-INF/`. This is an XML file whose
>   root element is `<appengine-web-app>`. ....

*Can I use mvn:appengine to run multiple modules and use dispatch.xml or dispatch.yaml?*

According to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed#dispatch_files):

> **All dispatch files are ignored when running the local development
>   server**. The only way to target instances is through their ports.

Comment: ..... An App Engine Java app must have a file named appengine-web.xml in its WAR, in the directory WEB-INF/. This is an XML file whose root element is <appengine-web-app>. .... 
But the problem is because I am using servlet 3.1 without web.xml, I can run multiples modules with dispatch file with servlets 2.5 because I can use dev_appserver.py, this is the reason to want to run dev_appserver.py using servlet 3.1